# Getting Attribute error, int object has no attribute bird. the previous answers didnt solve

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and cant figure out whats the issue, tried multiple solutions, but that didn't work.

posting from the main function

```
def main(genomes, config):
    nets = []
    ge = []
    birds = []  

    base = Base(680)
    pipes = [Pipe(600)]
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    score = 0

    run = True
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
            bird.move()
            ge[x].fitness += 0.1

            if output[0] > 0.5:
                bird.jump()

        add_pipe = False
        rem = []
```

It works the same in the loop below

```
        for pipe in pipes:
            for x,bird in enumerate(birds):
                if pipe.collide(bird):
                    ge[x].fitness -= 1
                    birds.pop(x)
                    nets.pop(x)
                    ge.pop(x)

                if not pipe.passed and pipe.x < bird.x:
                    pipe.passed = True
                    add_pipe = True

            if pipe.x + pipe.PIPE_TOP.get_width() < 0:
                rem.append(pipe)

            pipe.move()

        if add_pipe:
            score += 1
            for g in ge:
                g.fitness += 5
            pipes.append(Pipe(600))

        for r in rem:
            pipes.remove(r)
```

Here i'm getting that 'int object has no attribute bird' it works in other parts of the code

```
        for x.bird in enumerate(birds):
```

```
            if bird.y + bird.img.get_height() >= 680 or bird. y < 0:
                birds.pop(x)
                nets.pop(x)
                ge.pop(x)

        base.move()
        draw_window(win, birds, pipes, base, score)
```

Comment: Replace the . with , in  for x.bird in enumerate(birds):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used a dot instead of a comma:

```
for x, bird in enumerate(birds):
```

Enumerate functions typical format:

```
for index, value in enumerate(values):
```